# Odd angle object alignment

Tags: objects

I need to attach half of sphere to this surface, but I don't understand how do I go about aligning it.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select desired vertex.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> on the numpad (and maybe <kbd>5</kbd> to switch to the orthographic mode). It'll place viewport camera directly above your plane.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and choose "Cursor to selected".
4. Add a sphere. In the operator settings tick "Align to view".